# Ubuntu will not boot from my external hard drive

Tags: boot, 64-bit, 13.04, usb-drive, drive

I got a 16GB Flash Drive and turned it to a bootable USB with Pen Drive Linux using the 13.04 64 bit iso. I then booted from it and went to the setup procedure and installed it on a 500 GB external hard drive with no swap space, it was completely formated. Once installed I rebooted to the external hard drive, I waited several minutes only to see no progress and only a blank screen. Please help.

Comment: What kind of external drive do you have? Some drives are just not bootable.

Comment: Seagate 500 GB expansion drive USB 3.0

Comment: Where did you install the bootloader? When I did exactly what you did, it offered me to install the bootloader *on my internal hard disk* and I had to choose the correct path manually.

Answer (score 0):

When you install on the external drive, the simplest way to install it would be to make two partitions. First: Make a `swap` partition. This needs to be >= the amount of physical RAM you have installed to your computer. Second: Make the remaining memory an `ext4` linux partition, and set it's mount point to `/`. Choose the ext4 linux partition and install. Then, set your bios settings accordingly and boot into your new bootable linux drive.